# How to set up gerrit on tomcat7 with http auth on apache

Tags: apache2, tomcat7, gerrit, http-authentication

OS - Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTC

git, Tomcat7, mysql, apache2 were installed.

I configured tomcat7 to support SSL:
server.xml

```
<Connector port="4432" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
               keystoreFile="some_path"
               keystorePass="some_pass" />
```

And used mysql database:
context.xml

```
<Resource name="jdbc/ReviewDb"
          auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gerrit_reviewdb"
          username="gerrit"
          password="gerrit"
          maxActive="20"
          maxIdle="10"
          maxWait="-1"/>
```

I deployed gerrit on tomcat7 with type auth **development_become_any_account**.

Next I created file gerrit_auth.conf in folder /etc/apache2/sites-available

```
Listen 82
<VirtualHost *:82>
        ServerName localhost
        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyVia Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        AllowEncodedSlashes On
        <Proxy *>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Proxy>

        <Location /gerrit/login/>
                AuthType Basic
                AuthName "Gerrit Code Review2"
                AuthBasicProvider file
                AuthUserFile /var/opt/gerrit/users/passwords
                Require valid-user
        </Location>

        ProxyPass /gerrit/ https://localhost:4432/gerrit/ nocanon
        ErrorLog /var/opt/gerrit/apache_errorlog.log
        CustomLog /var/opt/gerrit/apache_customlog.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And chaged auth type to **http** in gerrit.config

```
[gerrit]
        basePath = /var/opt/gerrit/repositories
        canonicalWebUrl = https://my_gerrit_site:4432/gerrit
[database]
        type = mysql
        database = gerrit_reviewdb
        hostname = localhost
        username = gerrit
[index]
        type = LUCENE
[auth]
        type = http
[receive]
        enableSignedPush = false
[sendemail]
        smtpServer = localhost
[container]
        user = tomcat7
        javaHome = /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_79/jre
[sshd]
        listenAddress = *:29418
[httpd]
        listenUrl = proxy-http://localhost:82/
[cache]
        directory = cache
```

and restarted services apache2 and tomcat7.
Now when I go to https:// my_gerrit_site:4432/ I see tomcat7

> It works !

when I go to https:// my_gerrit_site:4432/gerrit I see

> Configuration Error
>
> Check the HTTP server's authentication settings.
>
> The HTTP server did not provide the username in the Authorization
>   header when it forwarded the request to Gerrit Code Review.
>
> If the HTTP server is Apache HTTPd, check the proxy configuration
>   includes an authorization directive with the proper location, ensuring
>   it ends with '/':
>
> ServerName my_gerrit_site
>
> ```
> ProxyRequests Off
> ProxyVia Off
> ProxyPreserveHost On
>
> <Proxy *>
>       Order deny,allow
>       Allow from all
> </Proxy>
>
> <Location /gerrit/login/>
>   AuthType Basic
>   AuthName "Gerrit Code Review"
>   Require valid-user
>   ...
> </Location>
>
> AllowEncodedSlashes On
> ProxyPass /gerrit/ http://.../gerrit/ nodecode </VirtualHost>
> ```

when I go to http:// my_gerrit_site:82/ I see

> Index of /
>
> Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at my_gerrit_site Port 82

when I go to http:// my_gerrit_site:82/gerrit/login/ I see
window with authentication, and when I login I see

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at [no address given] to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at my_gerrit_site Port 82
```

apache_errorlog.log

```
[Tue Jul 19 20:18:39.067497 2016] [proxy:warn] [pid 6382:tid 140713740175104] [client x.x.x.x:27949] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /gerrit/login/. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
```

catalina.out

```
[2016-07-19 20:18:18,855] [http-bio-4432-exec-6] ERROR com.google.gerrit.httpd.auth.container.HttpLoginServlet : Unable to authenticate user by Authorization request header.  Check container or server configuration.
```

What I do wrong? What settings I need change?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using Tomcat? Is it required? It's better to let gerrit work on it own.

Comment: Yes, I use tomcat because it is requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Problem was with apache2 and virtual host configuration.
```

When I tried enable proxy, proxy_http, proxy_ajp, ssl (a2enmod) I had some error related with one of two virtual hosts (files of their configurations were created and enabled when I try make http auth for my gerrit).
So when I disabled  (a2dissite)  virtual host with bad configuration I did not have errors.

**working apache2 configuration for http auth:**

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
Listen 4433

<VirtualHost *:4433>
        ServerName localhost

        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyVia Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        SSLProxyEngine on
        SSLProxyVerify none
        SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
        SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
        SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off

        #   SSL Engine Switch:
        #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
        SSLEngine on

        #   A self-signed (snakeoil) certificate can be created by installing
        #   the ssl-cert package. See
        #   /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian.gz for more info.
        #   If both key and certificate are stored in the same file, only the
        #   SSLCertificateFile directive is needed.
        SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

        #AllowEncodedSlashes On

        <Proxy *>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Proxy>

        <Location /gerrit/login/>
                AuthType Basic
                AuthName "Gerrit Code Review"
                AuthBasicProvider file
                AuthUserFile /var/opt/gerrit/users/passwords
                Require valid-user
        </Location>
         ProxyPass /gerrit/ https://localhost:4432/gerrit/

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog /var/opt/gerrit/apache_errorlog.log
        CustomLog /var/opt/gerrit/apache_customlog.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the canonocalWebUrl to the external url

```
canonicalWebUrl = https://my_gerrit_site:82/gerrit
```

Comment: unfortunately, It does not work. All are same errors and Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage (https://my_gerrit_site:82 and /gerrit). As I understand apache use http (not https)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use Tomcat with Gerrit, see more info here: https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/install.html#requirements

If your goal is to configure a reverse proxy, take a look here: https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-reverseproxy.html